# rgb to hex conversion

Tags: javascript, hex, rgb

What I'm trying to is:

1. Pick up RGB value from an element
2. Convert it to hex
3. Put it into a text field

**The first solution:**

(taken from this thread [RGB to Hex and Hex to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb))

```
function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
    return "#" + ((1 << 24) + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b).toString(16).slice(1);
}
```

The problem is: it only returns `#aN` no matter what I feed it. Is the function flawed or am I doing something wrong?

[See a demo here](http://codepen.io/hilja/pen/CwlIF)

**The second solution:**

From the same post as the upper mentioned.

```
function componentToHex(c) {
    var hex = c.toString(16);
    return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}

function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
    return "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
}
```

This works if I pass the value to as numbers `rgbToHex(255,255,255)` but does nothing if I try to feed the numbers as a variable `rgbToHex(rgbValue)`. (see the lines 19 to 25 in the demo)

[See the demo here](http://codepen.io/hilja/pen/stJhB)

All help appreciated :)

Comment: So, you pass one argument into a three-argument function and expect it to work?

Comment: Thanks :) I just go on a delete this stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function componentToHex(c) {
  var hex = c.toString(16);
  return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}

function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
  return "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
}

//Slap the rel values into the fields
$('.color').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();  

  var rgbVal = $(this).attr('rel');

  var rgbValSplit = rgbVal.split(",");

  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (!rgbValSplit[i]) {
      rgbValSplit[i] = 0;
    }
  }

  var finalHex = rgbToHex(+rgbValSplit[0], +rgbValSplit[1], +rgbValSplit[2]);

  $('.color-picker-rgb').val(rgbVal);
  $('.color-picker-hex').val(finalHex);

  $('body').css('background', finalHex);
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eiqbz

The main problem was that you needed to pass 3 parameters like it expects. The other problem was that it was expecting numbers, not strings. So when you pass it "191", `c.toString(16)` will evaluate to just `c`. If you pass it a number, like `191`, it will evaluate to the proper value.